# Manipulating label with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Scenario:
Three unchecked check-boxes, each with different id and value.
An empty paragraph (or label) with id = par.

```
[CB1] has value 1.  
[CB2] has value 2.  
[CB3] has value 3.
```

Now, when I click cb1 -> 'par' gets and prints the value of cb1.
Clicking on cb3, 'par' gets the value of cb1+cb3.
Clicking cb1, 'par' subtracts the value of cb1 and so on.. I think you get the point.

How can I achieve this with only HTML and JavaScript (without jQuery).

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" />

<p id="par"></p>
```

Comment: Done.
I just need to add or subtract the value in 'par' depending on that if the check-box is checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it: **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/85PCp/3/)** (updated to remove alert)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" onclick='checkClicked(event)'/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" onclick='checkClicked(event)'/>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" onclick='checkClicked(event)'/>
<p id="par"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkClicked(element)
{
    var targetElement = element.target;        
    var newVal = targetElement.value;
    if( !targetElement.checked )
    {
        newVal *= -1;
    }
    var currentVal = document.getElementById('par').innerHTML;
    if( currentVal )
    {
        newVal = parseInt(currentVal) + parseInt(newVal);
    }    
    document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = newVal;
}
```

Comment: One more thing.
How can I use this to make a sort of a 'wishlist' ?
i.e. I click on the cb and the title (in this case that can be the ID of it) to be displayed in an unordered list ?
Un-checking to remove it from the list ?

Comment: Your generosity is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="check1" onchange="alterP(this);"/>check1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="check2" onchange="alterP(this);"/>check2
</label>
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check3" value="check3" onchange="alterP(this);"/>check3
</label>
<p id="par"></p>
```

js Code

```
function alterP(obj) {
    var par = document.getElementById('par');
    var txt = (obj.checked) ? obj.value : "";
    par.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: This won't help me.
If I have all 3 cb's checked I should get result = 6
(1 + 2 + 3 = 6) ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", processCheck);
    document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("click", processCheck);
    document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", processCheck);

    function processCheck() {

        var theParagraph = document.getElementById("par");

        var currentValue = 0;

        if (!isNaN(parseInt(theParagraph.textContent))) {
            currentValue = parseInt(theParagraph.textContent)
        }

        if (this.checked) {
            theParagraph.textContent = currentValue + parseInt(this.value);
        }
        else {
            theParagraph.textContent = currentValue - parseInt(this.value);
        }
    }
</script>
```